# Why does "SELECT MOD(_number, 10) AS _mod;" yield error "query has no destination for result data"?

Tags: postgresql, variable-assignment, plpgsql

I'm trying to map the result of a modulo into a variable, but this yields the above error.
Here's a simplified snippet:

```
...
DECLARE
_mod int;

BEGIN
    ...
    SELECT MOD(_number, 10) AS _mod;
        
    IF 0 <> _mod THEN
    ...
END
```

Why does the SELECT-statement yield this error?

Comment: Have you tried SELECT MOD(_number, 10) INTO_mod

Comment: Welp, that worked. Thank you!

Comment: If all you do is check `0 <> _mod`, then drop `_mod` and simplify to `IF mod(_number, 10) <> 0 THEN ...` (And are you aware that NULL falls through?)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to store the `SELECT` result into the `_mod` variable. Then you should use `INTO`:

```
SELECT MOD(_number, 10) INTO _mod;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a SELECT to assign a value to a variable:

```
...
_mod := MOD(_number, 10);
    
IF 0 <> _mod THEN
....
```

Using variable assignment is more efficient than using `SELECT` to store the result of an expression.